# Bootstrap table sorting works inconsistently with LINQ

Tags: c#, twitter-bootstrap, linq, sorting, datatables-1.10

I have a `bootstrap datatable` in my view in a MVC application. I use the sorting functionality provided to sort it by a column called CreatedOn and load it on the screen.

```
<div class="container">
<div class="no-more-tables">
    <table id="tblTemplate" class="table table-advance dataTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th style="display:none">
                    ID
                </th>
                <th style="width:14%">
                    Type
                </th>
                <th style="width:25.5%;">
                    Subject
                </th>                   
                <th style="width:15%;">
                    Created By
                </th>
                <th style="width:15%;">
                    Created on
                </th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
            @foreach (var item in Model.lstBoxes)
            {
                <tr>
                    <td class="text-left" style="display:none">@item.Id</td>
                    <td class="text-left">@item.Type</td>
                    <td class="text-left">@item.Subject</td>
                    <td class="text-left">@item.CreatedBy</td>
                    <td class="text-left">@item.CreatedOn</td>   
                </tr>
            }
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
</div>
```

The sorting functionality script on load:

```
function initialSortCommon(tblName,colNo) {
$("#tblTemplate").dataTable(
    {
        "bDestroy": true
    }
    ).fnDestroy();
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#tblTemplate").dataTable({
        "bDestroy": true,
        "aaSorting": [[4, 'desc']],
        "oLanguage":
        {
            "sSearch": "Search all columns:",
        },
    });
});
}
```

The issue is the sorting behaves differently when fed a list using SQL Statements and when using Linq

```
 var lstBoxes = new List<Record>();
 var con = new SqlConnection(cs);
 con.Open();
 var command = new SqlCommand("SELECT ID,Type,Subject,CreatedBy,CreatedOn FROM Box", con);
 SqlDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();
 while (reader.Read())
 {
      lstBoxes.Add(new Record { Type = Convert.ToString(reader["Type"]), Id = Convert.ToString(reader["ID"]), Subject = Convert.ToString(reader["Subject"]), CreatedBy = Convert.ToString(reader["CreatedBy"]), CreatedOn = Convert.ToString(reader["CreatedOn"]) });
 }
 con.Close();
 return lstBoxes;
```

Using Linq:

```
var lstBoxes = db.Boxs.Select(s => new Record
 { Type = s.Type, Id = s.ID.ToString(), Subject = s.Subject, CreatedBy = s.CreatedBy, CreatedOn = s.CreatedOn.ToString() }).ToList();
return lstEvents;
```

Even though both tables return same data, the sorting on the Created on works perfectly with SQL Server but not with LINQ. Is this a known issue?

EDIT : Removed the descending by in LINQ to make both code consistent.

EDIT 2 : I checked the results of both lists. There is a difference in the way the date is being retrieved.
For example : In SQL, the field Convert.ToString(reader["CreatedOn"]) is being retrieved as 11/7/2017 9:51:26 AM where as in LINQ CreatedOn = s.CreatedOn.ToString() gives  Nov 7 2017  9:51 AM. This might be the cause of the issue. Is there a way the LINQ string be formatted similar to SQL result string?

Comment: But you have no sorting for the raw SqlCommand version...the order those records are returned is undefined, but may well happen to be in *ascending* created-on order (whereas your LINQ example uses OrderByDescending). Having said that you appear to be trying to sort on the client-side too, but I'm not that familiar with how the aaSorting option works, especially given you're passing a string column that holds date information (so it will only sort sensibly for certain date formats).

Comment: @DylanNicholson Removing the linq OrderByDescending does not fix the issue. So it looks like there is something inherently different between the result returned by SQL code and LINQ

Comment: Well other than the fact you've used `Convert.ToString(reader["CreatedOn"])` for the first and `s.CreatedOn.ToString()` for the second I can't see any reason there should be a difference (NB on my system neither of those produce a format suitable for sorting). As I said, if you don't specify an ORDER BY clause, the order of the records returned by the DB is undefined.

Comment: As Dylan said, without sorting given, SQL Server (I assume that's what it is) has NO defined sorting. There is no 'usual' or 'standard' sort - it just looks that way often because it *usually* comes back in order inserted. But nothing is promised. If you want consistency you need to sort explicity.

Comment: @DylanNicholson Is there internal difference between  Convert.ToString(reader["CreatedOn"]) and s.CreatedOn.ToString()? Don't see anything different which should affect the sorting.

Comment: It depends how reader["CreatedOn"] is returned. You haven't explicitly converted this anywhere to a DateTime object first, so it's probably coming back as an Object or SqlDateTime and may be, for instance, converted to a timestamp value (number of milliseconds since 1700 or some such). But in that case I'd think you'd see it like that in the output.

Comment: @DylanNicholson Check my latest Edit 2 and see if there is a way to get past that issue.

Comment: I would try changing `Record.CreatedOn` to be a DateTime first and see if that works - generally it's best to leave datetime's as they are until you need to display to a user.  But you can pass an explicit format to `ToString( )` to get that same format - "s" or "u" are built-in formats that are suitable for sorting.